# How to convert enum to string in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a class `User` as below with an enum field `Type`. How can I store string value of enum in SQL instead of numeric value?

```
 public class Student
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public UserTypeEnum Type { get; set; }
     public List<int> CourseIds { get; set; }
 }

 public enum UserTypeEnum
 {
     Bachelor = 10,
     Master = 11,
     PhD = 12
 }
```

I have tried to do it using EF Core but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your enum to string and retrieve it as enum with code below in your modelbuilder:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => (UserTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserTypeEnum), v
            ));
```